# Determine the LP spaces that contain a given function

Tags: lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

I was assigned this excercise:

> Determine $p$ so that  $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^3 - 1}$ belongs in the
>   $\mathfrak{L}^P(E)$ space, where $E=\mathbb{R}-\{1\}$

I've proceeded along this direction:

> $E$ is measurable because, for any given interval in $\mathbb{R}$
>
> $m(I)=m(I/E)+m(I\cap E)$
>
> Even  when $I$ contains the element $\{1\}$ we find that $m(I/E)=0$
>   because I/E is a set with a finite number of elements. On the other
>   hand $m(I\cap E)=m(I)$ in any case.
>
> Since $E$ is measurable, LP spaces are embedded in such a way that:
>   $\mathfrak{L}^{\infty}(E)\subset...\subset\mathfrak{L}^2(E)\subset\mathfrak{L}^1(E)$
>
> If $f\notin\mathfrak{L}^{1}$(E), then it doesn't belong in any LP
>   space over $E$. The function $|f(x)|$ aprroaches $+\infty$ as $x$
>   approaches $1$, therefore neither: $\int_{-\infty}^{1}|f(x)|dx$ or
>   $\int_{1}^{+\infty}|f(x)|dx$ converge.
>
> As a consequence, no LP space over $E$ contains $f$

Is my conclusion correct? Can you think of a more rigourous solution? Can it be done in a subtler way?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Unbounded functions can have bounded integrals, you can't reach that conclusion just based on the fact that $f$ is unbounded near $x=1$.

Comment: I've tried to use the comparison test with basic functions like 1/(x-1) and 1/x^3 but it got me nowhere. Can you give me one more hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inclusion of $L^p(E)$ spaces which you stated is correct provided the ambient set (the $E$ in our notation) has finite measure. When the measure of $E$ is unbounded, the inclusion does not hold in general. For example, take $E = \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+|x|}$ , $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $f\notin L^1(\mathbb{R})$, however, for any $p>1$ we have $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ (to see these claims one can use the monotonicity of $f$ and a comparison of the integral of $f$ with the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}$, $p \geq 1$).

In you example of $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^3 - 1}$  on $E:=\mathbb{R}\setminus \{1\}$ the integrability fails near $1$ (in a neighborhood of $\pm \infty$ the function $f$ is integrable with any exponent $p\geq 1$ as discussed above). Indeed, 
$$
\int\limits_{0}^1 \frac{dx}{|x^3 - 1|^p } =\int\limits_0^1 \frac{dx}{(1-x)^p (x^2 + x + 1)^p} \geq \frac{1}{3^p} \int\limits_0^1 \frac{dx}{(1-x)^p} ,
$$
but the last integral converges if and only if $p < 1$, hence $f$ is not integrable on $E$ with any exponent $p\geq 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for demonstrating the correct proceeding. I've tried this method on similar exercises and I've pretty well so far.